# zsh: automatically set environment variables for a directory

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

Let's say I have a project in:

```
~/working_dir
```

Whenever I run commands from this directory, I need to have certain environment variables set. So I can export them like so:

```
export VAR=value
```

However, there are a lot of these and it gets tedious, plus I forget sometimes and run a command only to have it fail because it's missing the environment variables that give it API keys or something.

Is there a way I can get zsh to remember these environment variables for this directory, so that any time I run any command from that directory it runs with those environment variables set?

Answer (score 12):

Compared with other tools designed for this, [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) is the best of them.

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the current directory. This allows **project-specific environment** variables without cluttering the `~/.profile` file.

What makes `direnv` distinct between other similar tools:

- `direnv` is written in Go, **faster** compared with its counterpart written in Python
- `direnv` supports **unload**ing environment variables when you quit from the specific dir
- `direnv` covers many shells

Similar projects

- [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) - one of the oldest (in a good way) environment-loading systems
- [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) - lightweight; doesn't support unloads; slow written in Python
- [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) - a feature-rich mixture of autoenv and [smartcd](https://github.com/cxreg/smartcd): enter/leave events, nesting, stashing (Zsh-only).
- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) - a pure bash solution that has a plugin system

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to do this - here's a [screencast](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2011/10/08/rocking-zsh-directory-specific-shell-profiles-screencast/), using the [Grml](http://grml.org/) ZSH [configuration](http://grml.org/zsh/#grmlzshconfig).

Further information:

- [Mikas Blog Post](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2009/05/30/directory-specific-shell-configuration-with-zsh/)
- The `chpwd_profiles()` function in the [Grml ZSH configuration](http://git.grml.org/?p=grml-etc-core.git;f=etc/zsh/zshrc;hb=HEAD#l1161).

Edit: This is actually pretty easy to do. Here's the relevant portion of your `~/.zshrc`:

```
function chpwd_profiles() {
    local profile context
    local -i reexecute

    context=":chpwd:profiles:$PWD"
    zstyle -s "$context" profile profile || profile='default'
    zstyle -T "$context" re-execute && reexecute=1 || reexecute=0

    if (( ${+parameters[CHPWD_PROFILE]} == 0 )); then
        typeset -g CHPWD_PROFILE
        local CHPWD_PROFILES_INIT=1
        (( ${+functions[chpwd_profiles_init]} )) && chpwd_profiles_init
    elif [[ $profile != $CHPWD_PROFILE ]]; then
        (( ${+functions[chpwd_leave_profile_$CHPWD_PROFILE]} )) \
            && chpwd_leave_profile_${CHPWD_PROFILE}
    fi  
    if (( reexecute )) || [[ $profile != $CHPWD_PROFILE ]]; then
        (( ${+functions[chpwd_profile_$profile]} )) && chpwd_profile_${profile}
    fi  

    CHPWD_PROFILE="${profile}"
    return 0
}
# Add the chpwd_profiles() function to the list called by chpwd()!
chpwd_functions=( ${chpwd_functions} chpwd_profiles )
```

Activate the profile for each directory you want:

```
zstyle ':chpwd:profiles:/path/to/directory(|/|/*)' profile NAME
```

And don't forget to actually make a profile:

```
chpwd_profile_NAME() {
    [[ ${profile} == ${CHPWD_PROFILE} ]] && return 1
    print "chpwd(): Switching to profile: $profile"

    export VAR=value
}
```

Edit #2: This would actually be rather neat to couple with [named directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14167062/1084945) [Stackoverflow.net].

Comment: There is nothing "easy" about this solution.

Comment: @rane agreed!  Looks pretty complex to me.

Comment: I am not an expert here but at the bottom of the .zshrc I added `chpwd_profiles` so if I open a new terminal tab it also performs a chpwd check.

Answer (score 5):

Even though this is an old question, I'd like to add this easy solution from https://coderwall.com/p/a3xreg/per-directory-zsh-config

```
// Add this to your ~/.zshrc
function chpwd() {
  if [ -r $PWD/.zsh_config ]; then
    source $PWD/.zsh_config
  else
    source $HOME/.zshrc
  fi
}
```

Comment: This works great, but you can probably skip lines 5-6 if you're already loading `.zshrc` when zsh is initialized.

Comment: @jstr It is to reset whatever the `$PWD/.zsh_config` did.

Comment: @aars it doesn't necessarily reset anything—it would only do that if you specifically ensure that every variable, alias, and function set in .zsh_config is unset or overwritten in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/horosgrisa/autoenv to achieve that. I use [antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen) to active that like this:

```
antigen bundle horosgrisa/autoenv
```

Then when you go into a directory with a `.env` file in it, it will be sourced and you can ser the variables there.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy to do by invoking `add-zsh-hook` on the `chpwd` event.

```
env_on_chdir () {
    case $PWD in
        /home/user/path/to/dir )
            export GO111MODULE=on;
            ;;
        /home/user/other/dir )
            export NO_COLOR=true;
            ;;
        * )
            # change background, when entering any other directory
            export GO111MODULE=off;
            unset NO_COLOR;
            ;;
    esac
}

# add env_on_chdir to chpwd_functions
add-zsh-hook chpwd env_on_chdir
```

For more, see https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/42-ZSH-Gem-8-Hook-function-chpwd.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not per directory, no, but if they are the same you can put them in your startup files (.bash_profile for bash, not sure what it is for zsh). Otherwise, I'd suggest just putting all the settings in a file in that directory and sourcing it before running commands. Not an ideal solution, but I think it's close to the best you'll be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that sets up the env and changes you to that directory.. then use it instead of `cd working_dir`